# docker-compose file for Postgre, Cordite, Corda node and backend server

Tags: docker, corda, cordite

I am looking for a docker-compose file that will include Postgre, Cordite, Corda Nodes, and the respective backend server (spring boot). I can run Postgre, Cordite, and Corda nodes individually but I want to group them together in a single file. I think it will be easy for deployment purposes.

Comment: Hi Arijit. You need a docker-conpose file that has each of these docker containers specified as a service. They can share a network so they are able to talk to each other using named DNS. Have you got an existing docker-conpose file you can share that doesn't seem to work? In the past I've used an orchestration script in the past to spin up each element and wait for it to be alive before spinning up the next service.

Comment: I don't have any docker-compose file. I am looking for a sample file that will spin up all these applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordite do a good open source example of this. This is the docker-compose.yml file: https://gitlab.com/cordite/cordite/blob/master/test/docker-compose.yml

This is the spin up script:
https://gitlab.com/cordite/cordite/-/blob/master/test/build_env.sh

This an example of the "spin up a service and wait for it to be ready" pattern:

```sh
docker-compose -p ${ENVIRONMENT_SLUG} up -d network-map
until docker-compose -p ${ENVIRONMENT_SLUG} logs network-map | grep -q "io.cordite.networkmap.NetworkMapApp - started"
do
    echo -e "waiting for network-map to start"
    sleep 5
done
```

So the `up` command starts the service and then the bash script reads the logs from the container every 5 seconds and checks for `io.cordite.networkmap.NetworkMapApp - started` in the log. Obviously you'll need to update what it looks for depending on which docker image you are spinning up.

Edit:
Some questions raised offline:

> "How to place the cordapp or mount the cordapp?"

You have 2 options, either create your own Docker image which extends from the cordite one and place your CorDapps in the CorDapp folder. Or use a volume mount to allow the running container to see your CorDapps (which will exist on the host). The details are here https://hub.docker.com/r/cordite/cordite/ Specifically you can mount into `/opt/corda/cordapps` to override the CorDapps.

> "How to add my springboot service for each node?"

Just add new services to the docker-compose.yml file which use your Springboot server docker image. There are 3 "normal" nodes in the example docker-compose.yml `emea`, `apac` and `amer`. I guess you want to create a new Springboot service for each one.

Comment: I have bootstrapped the network using the **network bootstrapper tool** and organize the folders accordingly(Check the nodes folder).
[Git link](https://github.com/arijitmhptr/cordite.git)
I have prepared the docker-compose and shell script as per the link you provided. I did some modification to mount the cordapps.
After executing the shell script, Postgre, Cordite NMS and Notary nodes are running successfully. But I am getting an error while executing the below command
`docker exec ${NODE_ID} rm network-parameters`
Error: "resource busy"

Comment: I don't use the network bootstrapper tool I'm afraid. The node.conf is created by the docker entrypoint script and the certs are created in the normal "production" way i.e. they are generated by the doorman and stored with the node.